# Performing Regression on Text and Image together in the most efficient way

Tags: keras, scikit-learn, regression, linear-regression

I have a dataset with texts and images. The texts are present in a CSV file, which I am able to read using Pandas. The CSVs contain the image names, and I have the corresponding pngs which are mentioned in my dataset as well.

The data format is as follows (roughly):

[image]

I would like to train a regression model to predict the labels, while making use of `Feature 1` and `Feature 2`, and the images that I have. The image names are the same as what is mentioned in the CSV.

I have tried training a Linear Model just for the CSV using SKLearn, and then training a CNN using Keras for the Images, and then averaging the regression values obtained, however, the results have been very poor (despite appropriate image transformation and pre-processing performed).

Now, I am pondering on how to improve my regression.

Will it be a good data science practice if I convert the images to a column or feature in the dataframe, and then apply a Linear Model? Or, is there a way to verify if the images would help me at all, before working on them. Each image is a very small sized RBG image.

I appreciate on any inputs on what is a right way to approach this.